# Does Async / FakeAsync wait for .then in spec blocks or just the component/class it's testing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I'm a bit concerned after one of my karma-jamine test was still passing with this code.

```
// before each above
comp = fixture.componentInstance

// This spec passes
it(`should not pass because async activity?`, () => {
    comp.router.navigate(['home']).then(() => {
        expect(true).toBe(true); // should not execute?
        // Should only execute if I placed done()?
    });
});
```

I thought that having the .then() was ok when we used somehting like async/fakeAsync wrapper

sample code taken from angular docs:

```
  it('should show quote after getQuote promise (async)', async(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => { // wait for async getQuote
      fixture.detectChanges();        // update view with quote
      expect(el.textContent).toBe(testQuote);
    });
  }));
```

Although this code also passes without any wrapper too:

```
it(`should also not pass?`, () => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(true).toBe(true); // But it passes!! : /
    });
  });
```

So this leaves me to believe that maybe the async / fakeAsync wrappers are only for intercepting async activity in the component/class we are testing and does not do anything for the spec we are testing.

Can anyone verify why the .then async code executes on the jasmine specs without the done() function? Why can we do this and is it really safe without adding the done() Function?

### Update

Thanks for the comment below:

I've done a expect(false).toBe(true) and

```
// This spec fails showing that the then in router executes
it(`should not pass because async activity?`, () => {
    comp.router.navigate(['home']).then(() => {
        expect(true).toBe(true); // should not execute?
        // Should only execute if I placed done()?
    });
});
// The then is skipped and spec passes (This should be expected ^^)
it(`then here is skipped without async wrapper`, () => {
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(false).toBe(true); // But it passes!! : /
  });
});
```

So I'm happy to see that the .whenStable() skips the then without a wrapper. Still a bit concerned with router.then()

Comment: Regarding first snippet with `comp.router.navigate(['home'])`, it's not totally clear if it passes because no assertions were detected. A good habit is to make test originally fail with `expect(true).toBe(false)` in order to detect false positives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async` and `fakeAsync` rely on zones, they wait for asynchronous code that is evaluated in *zones* that belong to a spec. It doesn't matter if a promise is created inside component or inside spec function, as long as it stays within a zone.

This

```
  it(`passes with Zone.js`, () => {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
  });
```

works because Jasmine is patched to work with Zone.js and support `async`/ `fakeAsync` helpers and causes a behaviour that is incompatible with original one. When fulfilled promise is chained with `then`, expectations will likely be detected and spec order will be preserved even without `async`, but this behaviour shouldn't be relied on.

This

```
  it(`fails with Zone.js`, () => {
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve)).then(() => {
      expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
  });
```

will fail in Zone.js.

And both examples will fail to detect expectations if Jasmine is not patched.

A good practice is to always return a promise from asynchronous spec (promise returns without `async`/`fakeAsync` helpers are supported in Jasmine 2.7 and higher):

```
it(`should not pass because async activity?`, async () => {
    await comp.router.navigate(['home']);
    expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer regrading info about zones, It's really helpful. : )

Answer (score 0):

async is a wrapper to flag to people calling the function warning them that the function contains asynchronous code. I'm afraid I can't really explain what difference putting async on your tests has, however I think I can explain your confusion about the done function.

First let me clear up something else, your first and third tests are always going to pass. Remember that an empty test passes:

```
it(`passes`, () => {
});
```

So if you add an if statement with an expect that should pass then the test will pass whether the if statement is true or not.

```
it(`still passes`, () => {
  if (21 < 42) {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  }
});
```

If you want to use the done function with a jasmine test then you need to pass it in as a parameter to the test. Here are a couple of examples:

```
it(`passes because done in wrong place`, (done) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
     expect(false).toBe(true);
  }, 500);
  done();
});

it(`correctly does not pass as expect trigered`, (done) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
     expect(false).toBe(true);
     done();
    }, 500);
});
```

Remember Jasmine will timeout any test after 5 seconds unless you change jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

You want to be using the done function to let Jasmine know that your test is finished. I'm not sure it's really needed but I guess there could be an argument that it could make a test with a callback function slightly more readable.

Comment: The behaviour that is described in OP is very specific to Angular async/fakeAsync helpers and the fact that Jasmine/Mocha is patched by Zone.js to support them. The helpers were introduced to get rid of original Jasmine workflow and `done` callback.

Comment: @estus So what would you suggest when you see a post that says I would like to ask about (a) because I see I see (b) and (c) happening, but you don't know much about (a) but you do understand why (b) and (c) are happening.

Comment: I have now read up on what async/fakeAsync are supposed to do but in my tests they don't seem to be having that effect. Looks like I'll have to ask my own question when I have time later.

Comment: I'd either leave the question to users who know about a,b & c, or consider it a chance to learn about a, or answer b & c only, like you did. Any of the options may work for the OP. Even if it didn't, the answer may be useful to somebody who has a related problem. As for fakeAsync, it's Angular pseudo-async alternative to jasmine.clock with some magic.